# Custom bindingHandler for a custom dropdown box in knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

**Updated:** Here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MikeWills/XRUFf/).

I am having issues with my custom handler for my dropdown. I can't use .subscribe() on the event to trigger filling my other dropdown list (in a cascade dropdown list). I am building a list of leave types for our leave request system. This all resides in a table of multiple days per request. My JSON looks like:

```
[{
"Id": 4,
"Title": "Comp Time Used",
"ParentId": 0,
"ChildRequired": false,
"HourTypeCodes": [{
    "Id": "07",
    "Title": "COMP TIME USED"
}, {
    "Id": "35",
    "Title": "COMP TIME USED WWTP"
}]
}, , {
"Id": 1,
"Title": "Vacation",
"ParentId": 1,
"MapToCode": "04"
"ChildRequired": true,
"HourTypeCodes": [{
    "Id": "04",
    "Title": "VACATION"
}]
}, {
"Id": 24,
"Title": "Vacation",
"ParentId": 1,
"MapToCode": "04",
"ChildRequired": false,
"HourTypeCodes": [{
    "Id": "04",
    "Title": "VACATION"
}]
}, {
"Id": 25,
"Title": "Vacation Adjust - Fire",
"ParentId": 1,
"MapToCode": "45",
"ChildRequired": false,
"HourTypeCodes": [{
    "Id": "45",
    "Title": "VAC-FIRE-ADJUST."
}]
}
```

Which would create a dropdown list similar to:

```
<select name="RequestType[]" data-bind="leaveTypeDropDown: RequestType()"><option value="">(Select)</option><option value="4">Comp Time Used</option><optgroup label="Vacation"><option value="24">Vacation</option><option value="25">Vacation Adjust - Fire</option></optgroup></select>
```

This then builds another drop down which the user selects the hours type (in the few cases where there is an option. In the case of "Comp Time" you can choose "Comp Time Used" or "Comp Time Used WWTP" (special payroll stuff I don't understand).

I am migrating my project from an older MVC 2 application to a knockout.js based form. In the old application, I was able to use this function to create the dropdown:

```
    function LoadRequestType(obj) {
        var items = "<option value=''>(Select)</option>";
        var savedParent = 0;
        $.each(jsonRequestType, function (i, item) {
            if ((savedParent != item.ParentId) && (savedParent != 0))
                items += "</optgroup>";
            if (item.ChildRequired)
                items += "<optgroup label='" + item.Title + "'>";
            else {
                items += "<option value='" + item.Id + "'";
                if ($(obj).prev("input").val() == item.Id)
                    items += " selected";
                items += ">" + item.Title + "</option>";
            };
        });
        $(obj).html(items);
    }
```

I can run this function as is with knockout

```
    ko.bindingHandlers.leaveTypeDropDown = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
           // Fill the drop down list.
            LoadRequestType(element);
        }
    };
```

and it will create the dropdown. But when I change a value and have a .subscribe() on the value, nothing happens from there. I am guessing there is a trigger of some sort missing, I just can't figue out what.

Here is what I have tried:

```
        function LeaveDay(dateOfLeave, timeOfLeave, hoursRequested, requestType, relationship, natureOfIllness, timesheetCode, isAllDay) {
            var self = this;
            // trimmed to only show relavant code
            self.RequestType = ko.observable(requestType);

            self.RequestType.subscribe(function (newValue) {
                alert("test");
            });
        }

        function DayViewModel() {
            var self = this;
            self.days = ko.observableArray([
                new LeaveDay(new Date().toString("MM/dd/yyyy"), "8:00 am", 8, 0, "", "", 0, "", true)
            ]);
        }
```

Any ideas?

I'll see if I can figure out how to do a jsFiddle to show what is happening and update with a link.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use amplify.js and its pub/sub events. I've just started working with it and it helps quite a bit with loose coupling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Register own `change` event callback for your `<select>`:

```
    ko.bindingHandlers.leaveTypeDropDown = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            // Fill the drop down list.
            LoadRequestType(element);

            // register event handler where bound observable will be changed
            ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, 'change', function(){
                var observable = valueAccessor();
                observable(element.value);
            });
        }
    };
```

And **do not forget** to change your markup (`()` stripped):

```
<select name="RequestType[]" data-bind="leaveTypeDropDown: RequestType">
```

Modified fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XRUFf/29/

You will see your alert after every selection, and RequestType value in the 3rd column (bound by me just for illustration) as well.

Comment: Thank you! I had seen that floating around but didn't see what exactly it was for or it's usage.